# Mongo command not found on Mac using zsh?

Tags: mongodb, bash, terminal, environment-variables, zsh

I installed Mongo Db via the official site. I also created the below folder

```
~/data/db
```

I added the mongo files in the location as follows :

```
/usr/local/mongodb
```

Im using zsh so setting the environment variables as suggested in the bash_profile doesnt work for me.
My .zshrc file looks as follows

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export MONGO_PATH=/usr/local/mongodb
export PATH=MONGO_PATH/bin:$PATH
```

I also ran the source command as follows :

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

However even after trying variations of various answers, I still get :

```
zsh: command not found: mongo
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Missed dollar sign. `export PATH=$MONGO_PATH/bin:$PATH`

Comment: `PATH=MONGO_PATH/bin:$PATH` needs to be `PATH=$MONGO_PATH/bin:$PATH` - note the extra `$`!

Comment: does mac say anything about the mongo you downloaded is not trusted/identified? zsh should be almost identical to bash in terms of PATH

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem when I try to install Mongo with [official doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)

[This](https://gist.github.com/nrollr/9f523ae17ecdbb50311980503409aeb3) instruction help me to run MongoDB on MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

1. Try `mongod --version`
2. If there is no Mongodb installed try enter `brew install mongodb`
3. After this check installation again with `mongod --version`
4. Then use `brew services start mongodb` to run MongoDB on startup

Comment: `No available formula with the name "mongodb". Did you mean mongosh or monetdb` error on 4 step, any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Try `brew install mongodb-community-shell`, as suggested by [this](https://developpaper.com/fix-mac-brew-installation-mongodb-error-no-available-formula-with-the-name-mongodb/).

My case:

I did try `brew services start mongodb` to solve it, but face this issue:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "mongodb". Did you mean mongosh or monetdb?
```

Answer (score 1):

this one worked for me.in new macbook or air we cant find `.zhrc` or `bash`

in new mac its `.zprofile`. so change the path in `.zprofile`

`export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH`